# Distinguishing between I-type and R-type Instruction format in MIPS

Tags: mips, instructions

In MIPS, I wonder if there is a way to tell if an instruction, by just looking at the machine code, is an I-type or R-type instruction?

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for something quick and dirty, the op-code (6 most significant bits) of almost all R-type instructions is set to `0`.

Of course in a real CPU there would be a more complicated test that would deal with all the possible exceptions.

See [this chart](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Instruction_Formats#Opcodes).